# Kusto Query Language: How to store hundreds of objects in an array

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to query a set of a different tables, sometimes located on different kusto clusters, based on the values I have set in a `pack_array`, something like:

```
let dyn_array = pack_array("a", "b", "c");
cluster('cluster1').database("db2").Table3
| where ColumnofInterest in (dyn_array)
```

The problem is, I currently have like 1000 values (ideally more) that I would like to fill dyn_array with. Yet, when I fill it with say, more than 50 or so, it will breakdown and KQL will throw errors and will not query. This is exacerbated if I add in other `let` commands like time on top of it (e.g., `let startTime = ago (360d);`

How can I pass in many values to my array (or an alternative) so I can satisfy this requirement?

`| where ColumnofInterest in (dyn_array)`

Comment: That's funny since they tell you to use `where ... in ...` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-query-complexity

Comment: *"when I fill it with say, more than 50 or so, it will breakdown and KQL will throw errors and will not query"* - could you please include the full error message?